# Python doesn't allow me to do match.group() with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a regex in Python to just get the digits from a string. However, when I run match.group(), it says that the object `list` has no attribute `group`. What am I doing wrong? My code as typed pasted into the terminal, and the terminal's response. Thanks.

```
>>> #import regex library
... import re
>>> 
>>> #use a regex to just get the numbers -- not the rest of the string
... matcht = re.findall(r'\d', dwtunl)
>>> matchb = re.findall(r'\d', ambaas)
>>> #macht = re.search(r'\d\d', dwtunl)
... 
>>> #just a test to see about my regex
... print matcht.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> print matchb.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> 
>>> #start defining the final variables
... if dwtunl == "No Delay":
...     dwtunnl = 10
... else:
...     dwtunnl = matcht.group()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> if ambaas == "No Delay":
...     ammbaas = 10
... else:
...     ammbaas = matchb.group()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Read the docs: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.findall :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.findall()` doesn't return a match object (or a list of them), it always returns a list of strings (or a list of tuples of strings, in the case of there being more than one capturing group). And a list doesn't have a `.group()` method.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(\w)(\W)")
>>> regex.findall("A/1$5&")
[('A', '/'), ('1', '$'), ('5', '&')]
```

`re.finditer()` will return an iterator that yields one match object per match.

```
>>> for match in regex.finditer("A/1$5&"):
...     print match.group(1), match.group(2)
...
A /
1 $
5 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `re.findall(r'\d', ambaas)` returns a `list`. You can iterate over the list, like:

```
for i in stored_list
```

Or just `stored_list[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall()` returns a list of strings, not a `match` object.  You might mean `re.finditer`.